# java.sql.SQLException:null During connecting to MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm just trying to connect remotely to my MySQL server with a  java application .But while running the code getting `java.sql.SQLException:null`,  message from server: "Host '202.146.192.145' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".I have double checked the host, username and password.Following is the Database connection code given in my application.

```
package com.db;
public class Dbbean {
    public Connection con;
    public Statement st;
    public PreparedStatement pst;
    public Dbbean(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://phpmyadmin202.sample.com/dbname","user","password");
            st=con.createStatement();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void close() throws SQLException{
        con.close();
    }
    public ResultSet execsql(String sql) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet r=st.executeQuery(sql);
        return(r==null)?null:r;
    }
    public int updatesql(String sql) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

        int r=st.executeUpdate(sql);
        return(r==0)?0:r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IP is not in the trusted IP list in the database. Ask your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

**Check you users and priveleges in you server.**

Answer (score 0):

From what I've noticed, you have missed port number for the connection url. Default port number is 3306. Try adding "jdbc:mysql://remotename:port/dbname" in the connection URL. Also check you have been granted privileges on the database server.